# Agora Chat Callkit: how to send native call invitation on app closed?

Tags: android, voip, agora.io, agora, agora-implementation

we have integrated following library from Agora:
https://docs.agora.io/en/agora-chat/develop/callkit?platform=android

but it doesn't explains how do we send call invite on app closed as this one:
[image]

Does the Agora handles the Voip notifications themselves or what would be the procedure to implement the call invite screen on app closed?

Comment: Currently, Push notifications for Android client apps are sent using Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) .
The Chat Server communicates with FCM that will deliver a push notification to an Android device where your app is installed.
See [here](https://docs.agora.io/en/agora-chat/develop/offline-push?platform=android#set-up-push-notifications)

Comment: @CarlsonYuan thanks a lot, we got it figured out eventually